# Order of operations with recursion confusing

Tags: python, recursion

In this piece of code

```
def maxVal(toConsider, avail):
if toConsider == [] or avail == 0:  
    result = (0, ())

elif toConsider[0].getCost() > avail:  
    result = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)  

else:  
    nextItem = toConsider[0] 
    withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:],
                                 avail - nextItem.getCost())
    withVal += nextItem.getValue()  
    withoutVal, withoutToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:], avail)

    if withVal > withoutVal:
        result = (withVal, withToTake + (nextItem,))
    else:
        result = (withoutVal, withoutToTake)
return result
```

How is withVal not some sort of infinite loop because it gets it's assigned variables from the function, which means it repeats again without the first variable so shouldn't it just keep going and going? Until avail reaches 0 but then it also is added to 'nextItem' which drives my head in.

So I know that

```
withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:],
                             avail - nextItem.getCost())
```

comes before

```
withVal += nextItem.getValue()
```

And doesn't for an infinite loop, so my question is how is withVal able to stay in order with 2 assignments considering the first example demonstrates that it recalls the function again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is guaranteed to terminate since `avail == 0` isn't the only stopping condition. It also suffices to have `toConsider == []`. When you call the code

```
withVal, withToTake = maxVal(toConsider[1:],
                             avail - nextItem.getCost())
```

Notice in particular the snippet `[1:]`. This says that you're only passing in most of the `toConsider` list. It's getting smaller each time by 1, and eventually its length will hit 0. Since the recursion eventually ends, you're able to finally get to the next assignment `withVal += nextItem.getValue()`.

Sometimes getting to the bottom of questions like this can be made easier in the beginning with pythontutor.com, which allows you to step through and visualize code one piece at a time and see which values change in which order. I'm not affiliated with them, but they have an okay product for small problems like this.